# Unable to install Go packages

Tags: go

When I run `go get`, I get a permission Denied error and when I try `sudo go get` I get a GOPATH not set error.

```
utkbansal@Dell:~$ go  get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc: open /usr/lib/go/bin/godoc: permission denied

utkbansal@Dell:~$ sudo go  get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Here are the result of my $PATH, go env and which go commands.

```
utkbansal@Dell:~$ which go
/usr/lib/go/bin/go

utkbansal@Dell:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/utkbansal/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"


utkbansal@Dell:~$ $PATH
bash: /usr/lib/go/bin:/home/utkbansal/miniconda/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/go/bin: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

I am using go1.5 from this PPA https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/lxd-stable (ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable)

Comment: Do you use a proxy ? And for your second error, are you sure that your Gopath contains the src, pgk and bin directories ?

Comment: ```utkbansal@Dell:~$ ls $GOPATH``` gives
```bin  pkg  src```

Comment: Don't use `sudo`. Once you've used it, you've then changed the permissions of associated folders (hence permission denied). Remove `/home/utkbansal/go` and below, and start over.

Comment: @elithrar: the error is not because of the permissions it is due to the fact that the godoc binary he tries to update sits in /usr/lib/go/bin/godoc

Comment: @Srgrn what should i do then?

Comment: @elithrar removing the go folder and trying to install the package again doesn't work either. It gives the same error.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`godoc` seems to be an exception to the general `go get` practice, because it installs to the go installation (`$GOROOT/bin`) instead of `$GOPATH`. So, if you really need to update `godoc` (why?), what you need to do is:

1. Log in as root (or `su`, or `sudo su`, or ...)
2. Set `$GOPATH` to your normal user `$GOPATH` (`"/home/utkbansal/go"`)
3. Update `godoc`, using `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`, or all tools
4. *Set the appropriate permissions on for your `$GOPATH`*, i.e. `chown -R utkbansal:utkbansal $GOPATH` (still as root)

That should work I guess. BUT: Why would you want to update `godoc`? If you just want one specific tool that is not pre-installed, you should be able to `go get` it without root privileges.

Comment: Set $GOPATH to your normal user $GOPATH ("/home/utkbansal/go")
This needs to be done with export GOPATH=/home/..../go

Comment: It would be better if @utkbansal installed Go in their home directory. If an error occurs while using the IDE, they should ensure that the Go installation in their home directory is selected within the IDE.

Answer (score 10):

mrd0ll4r has an excellent explanation of the problem, though I would like to share an easier way to install `godoc`. Assuming you set your `$GOPATH` in your `.bashrc` (or similar) try:

```
sudo -E go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

With the `-E` flag you perserve your current environment variables (including `$GOPATH`).

Comment: I had to do: `sudo -E /usr/local/go/bin/go  get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`. Else, I get `sudo: go: command not found` (even though my root shell has a path to `go`  :/

Answer (score 6):

See @mrd0ll4r answer which is better. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/33755566/989659 )

**UPDATE**

since you used the -u flag it first tries to update the package which is already installed and have a binary at /usr/lib/go/bin/godoc

when you ran it with sudo it doesn't have your enviroment variables so it no longer has the GOPATH variable

you can enter root mode and run it from there

```
sudo su 
export GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
export GOPATH="/home/utkbansal/go"
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
# other commands
exit
```

Comment: ```root@Dell:/home/utkbansal# go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Comment: sorry I forgot a line  export GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
export GOPATH="/home/utkbansal/go"

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't the root permission, we can build binary into `$GOPATH/bin`, Let me use `godoc` as example

```
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
cd $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
go build -o $GOPATH/bin/godoc
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem appear in my computer. Problem was, that I had install go, but not godoc. And the simples was install standart godoc (on my fedora dnf install)

```
sudo dnf install golang-godoc
```

Thank mrd0ll4r for explanation what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers in this thread and couldn't get godoc installed.

`sudo apt install golang-golang-x-tools`

I believe I now have a version of godocs which is older than my Go version but I will live with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when installing delve

```
go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: open /usr/local/go/bin/dlv: permission denied
```

But I solved it by using another way different form @mrd0ll4r, you needn't change anything.

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

It works well.

refer to [command not found when using sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/709515/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score -1):

`sudo GOPATH=path_to_go_installation go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...

`sudo` - run followed commands as root.

`GOPATH=path_to_go_installation` - sets environment variable for `sudo` session.

`go get` - installs package into `GOPATH` that was set on the previous step.